# How to Avoid HTML Encoding in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm calling a Web Service method to get some html data. When I set the returned data as innerHtml for a div tag then it is displayed as-is (literal text). I don't want my returned html data to be encoded. How to do this?

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGetLaboratories").click(function () {
                var oService = new LaboratoryService();
                var fResult = oService.send(); // returns some html data

                $("#divResult").html(fResult);
            });
        });
```

Here is my html code:

```
<input id="btnGetLaboratories" type="button" value="Get Laboratories" />
    <div id="divResult">

    </div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're seeing the literal HTML tags of `fResult` on the rendered page? Could you show an example of data it returns and how it looks on the page? It's not very clear what the problem is.

Comment: For example, if the return data is `<b>hello</b>`, then my div (i.e., divResult) innerHtml becomes `<b>hello</b>`; This is not what I'm expecting. I expect that a **hello** to be rendered on page.

Comment: @user3747698 have you checked with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetLaboratories").click(function () {
            var oService = new LaboratoryService();
            var fResult = oService.send(); // returns some html data

            var newData = $('<div/>').html(fResult).text();

            $("#divResult").html(newData);
        });
    });
```

Hope it will help